# Create a race track on a landcape with banked corners

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, geometry

I would like to create a racetrack on a landscape with banked corners.

I am able to start with a landscape, add a Bezier curve, and use the curve and array modifier to create a track which follows the terrain and is level. However, I would like to bank the corners. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

For example, is there way to follow a curve and independently specify the angle of rotation in along the curve?

The blend file for this example is located here - [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicate the curve, then use the **Follow Path** constraint with **Follow Curve Checked.**

[image]

With the constraint, the banking is influence by the curves tilt. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> in curve edit mode.

[image]